# How to merge rows contain same id and remove null values of duplicate rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Here My Table contains five columns that are the same value and the other three columns are mixed null values due to this duplicate columns are generating.Help me to resolve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the many articles found a solution, we need to use the group by selecting the value which you need distinct and apply conditions where we need to merge columns

[image]

After applying the aggregation result will be given below

[image]

Comment: Is that meeting your expectation? or you still searching for some solution?

Comment: Pls, post if you have any alternative ones and it will be useful to a community members.